# Proxying connection to MySQL without MySQL Proxy

Tags: mysql, proxy, database-connection, mysql-proxy

[MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-proxy.html) sounds like the best option to proxy a connection to MySQL server in order to modify queries online except that [it only supports scripts in Lua](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-proxy-scripting.html), AFAIK.

Is it possible to script MySQL Proxy behavior in languages other than Lua? Ideally, C, C++ or C#?

If not, how do I look through and amend the traffic between MySQL client and server (e.g., in C#) without fully implementing the [MySQL client/server protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to build mysql proxy in other languages.

Here are few reference implementations in java

https://github.com/MPjct/JMPjct

https://github.com/Flipkart/phantom-mysql-proxy

To check the traffic between Mysql client and server , you can print the following param.

Com_Query.loadFromPacket(packet).query